Firestore Missing or insufficient permissions with App Check
I'm testing a debug flutter app on android device to access a Firestore database without authentication, so I added a debug token to the Firebase AppCheck console and turned the Firestore enforcement off to test the app on debug mode and the requests are marked as verified but I'm still getting "Missing or insufficient permissions" when I try to access the Firestore data and it doesn't work unless I change the Firestore rule to allow read, write: if true (make it public).
Here is the code used when initializing the app:
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug);
FirebaseAppCheck.instance.setTokenAutoRefreshEnabled(false);
String? token = await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.getToken();
runApp(const MyApp());

And I used the below as FireStore Rule:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {

            // allow read, write: if request.time < request.auth.token.exp && request.auth.token.app_check == true;  
            allow read, write: if request.appCheck.token != null;
        }
    }
}

